# Merging or Combining two onEdit trigger functions

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have script for Google Sheets that I collected on interwebs and got some help here. No I have 2 `onEdit` in conflict. I overcome that by creating script Trigger for `onEdit2`. It works but I don't think it is the best solution. Could you help get those two separated `onEdit` with if functions into one, please?

```
//Dependent Dropdown list
function onEdit(e){ // Function that runs when we edit a value in the table.
  masterSelector(master1,master2,master3,master4);
  var activeCell = e.range; // It returns the coordinate of the cell that we just edited.
  var val = activeCell.getValue(); // Returns the value entered in the column we just edited.
  var r = activeCell.getRow(); // returns the row number of the cell we edit.
  var c = activeCell.getColumn(); // returns the column number of the cell we edit.

  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  if (wsName === masterWsName && c === firstLevelColumn && r > masterNumberOfHeaderRows) { // the if delimits the section sensitive to modification and action of the onEdit.
    applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r);
  } else if (wsName === masterWsName && c === secondLevelColumn && r > masterNumberOfHeaderRows){
      applySecondLevelValidation(val,r);
    }
} // end of onEdit

// addRow by checkboxes 
function onEdit2(e) {
    masterSelector(master1,master2,master3,master4);
  //IF the cell that was edited was in column 4 = D and therefore a checkbox AND if the cell edited was checked (not unchecked):
  if (e.range.columnStart === 4 && e.range.getValue() === true) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
        row = sheet.getActiveCell()
        .getRow(),
        //(active row, from column, numRows, numColumns)
        rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 30);
    sheet.insertRowAfter(row);
    rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(row + 1, 1));
    //Reset checked boxes in column 4
    sheet.getRange(row,4,2,1).setValue(false);
  }
}
```

Whole script is [here](https://script.google.com/d/1TIX8coKfMmv7AfN5X109cDStIm2FgzwVdnIZtfBCmrmKjAih6eRnmeZ4/edit?usp=sharing), if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A script cannot contain two functions with the same name. Rename your first `onEdit` function to `onEdit1` (actually it will be better to assign a descriptive name) and the second function as `onEdit2`, then put them both in one function named `onEdit` and pass the parameter `e` to both of them:

```
function onEdit(e){
  onEdit1(e);
  onEdit2(e);
}
```

#### Related:

- [Two OnEdit functions not working together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030085/)
- [Best Practices for Multiple OnEdit Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60493793/1595451)
- [How to run multiple onEdit functions in the same google script (google sheets)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55262195/1595451)
- [Bracketing multiple onEdit functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58985077/1595451)