# Is there a way to combine two scripts for check boxes to date and move to the bottom of the page?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, combinations

I am trying to merge both codes so that when the checkbox is checked it will add a date in the column to the right and move the row to the bottom of the page. However I can't seem to figure this out. I've only recently started scripting.

Can someone assist with combining the code?

```
var SORT_COLUMN_INDEX = 2;
var ASCENDING = true;
var NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS = 1;


var activeSheet;


function autoSort(sheet) {
  
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();


  if (NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS > 1) {
    range = range.offset(NUMBER_OF_HEADER_ROWS, 1);
  }

 
  range.sort( {
    column: SORT_COLUMN_INDEX,
    ascending: ASCENDING
  } );
}

function onEdit(event) {
  var editedCell;
  
  activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  editedCell = activeSheet.getActiveCell();

  if (editedCell.getColumn() == SORT_COLUMN_INDEX) {
    autoSort(activeSheet);
  }
}

function onOpen(event) {
  activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  autoSort(activeSheet);
}

function onInstall(event) {
  onOpen(event);
}
```

```
  /** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
const SHEET_TAB_NAME = "Movies";
const COLUMN_TO_CHECK = "2";
const DATE_TIME_COL_OFFSET = 1;

function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const currentSheet = range.getSheet();

  if(currentSheet.getName() !== SHEET_TAB_NAME) return;

  const column = range.getColumn();

  if(column != COLUMN_TO_CHECK) return;

  const dateTimeStamp = new Date();

  range
    .offset(0, DATE_TIME_COL_OFFSET)
    .setValue(dateTimeStamp)
}
```

I've tried seperating the scripts in different script files and tried meerging them, also searched reddit and youtube, couldnt find the answer

Comment: Will this thread be your answer? https://stackoverflow.com/q/62602747/7108653